# Reload page with new params js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to refresh page on **change** of my select box value add this value to url as a query string here is my code

```
<select name="country_id" id="country" class="validate-select" title="Country">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
</select>
```

And the JS code i wrote for this is

```
jQuery('#country').on('change', function () {
   var url = window.location.href;    
   url += '?country='+jQuery(this).val()+''
   window.location.href = url;
});
```

Its working fine but its always adding new param like this not replacing previous one

> ?country=KW?country=QA

I want to remove previous param before adding new one and refresh page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `window.location.href = url` to `window.location=window.location.href + "?country=" + this.value` `window.location.href` is just returns the href (URL) of the current page please find below snippet as well to understand

And for remove querystring from href you can add `.split('?')[0]` after getting url like `window.location.href.split('?')[0]`

```js
$(function(){
      $("#country").change(function(){
        debugger;
        window.location=window.location.href.split('?')[0] + "?country=" + this.value
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country_id" id="country" class="validate-select" title="Country">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
</select>
```

Comment: gald it helps please mark as answered for future references

Answer (score 2):

Try using `window.location.search` you can update a param value or add a new param

```
jQuery('#country').change(function(){
    query = 'country=' + $(this).val();
    window.location.search = query;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
url+=url.split('?')[0]+jQuery(this).val()+'';
```

or you could alternatively declare your url var as `url = window.location.host;`